# Android - Communicate with Bluetooth subsystem (BlueZ)

Tags: android, android-ndk, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I'm looking for a way to do periodic bluetooth inquiry's from my Android Smartphone (HTC Desire with Android 4.0.1). The Device is rooted and it is a custom Rom installed so that I have full privileges.
I already wrote a shellscript, which uses hcitool, hciconfig and hcidump to do the inquiry's. That works fine so far, but it is a little to slow for me. I guess that's because of my dirty workaround of using an android-app to execute a shellscript from linux.
Although I got problems by killing the executed processes via my App.

So I'd like to find a way to inquire BT Devices from the Android API.
I found out that there is no possibility 'til now to do this, but i read about the bluez API which is possibly able to fit my requests.
Does anyone have any links, tips or advises for me?

I haven't found anything useful :/

Thanks in advance.

---

*Edit (2012-09-28):*

Okay, I think I'm a little closer to the solution now.
I downloaded the source of blueZ library from: [bluez.org](http://www.bluez.org/)
Then i put the important files (hci.h, bluetooth.h, hcilib.h and their sourcefiles) into the jni folder of my android project and compiled them into my shared library.
I wrote a JNI Wrapper around the function

```
hci_inquiry(int dev_id, int len, int nrsp, const uint8_t *lap,inquiry_info **ii, long flags)
```

and followed the advises of [this](http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/c404.html) book to do my inquiry. Everything fine 'til here.

But when I start the inquiry, the function

```
 dev_id = hci_get_route(NULL);
```

always returns -1, and I can't continue.

Bluetooth is activated, and i already tried to grant root access to my application. Not better :(

Anything I did wrong until here? Isn't it allowed to use BlueZ HCI commands from a android app?
I mean JBlueZ doesn't do anything else is it?

My native code looks like this:

```
inquiry_info *ii = NULL;
int max_rsp, num_rsp;
int dev_id, sock, len, flags;
int i;
char addr[19] = { 0 };
char name[248] = { 0 };

dev_id = hci_get_route(NULL);
if (dev_id < 0 ) {
    LOGI("ERROR ON finding Device ID");
    return;
}
sock = hci_open_dev( dev_id );
if (sock < 0) {
    LOGI("ERROR ON opening socket");
    return;
}

len  = 8;
max_rsp = 255;
flags = IREQ_CACHE_FLUSH;
ii = (inquiry_info*)malloc(max_rsp * sizeof(inquiry_info));


num_rsp = hci_inquiry(dev_id, len, max_rsp, NULL, &ii, flags);

//##################################################################################
LOGI("INQUIRY Executed!!!");

(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, obj, callBackID, num_rsp);

free(ii);
close(sock);
```

Thank you for any help.